# Including pipe running Oracle sql from DOS batch script

Tags: oracle, dos, sqlplus, batch-file

We use the approach below to run SQL from a DOS batch script.

The model works fine but this specific code doesn't work.  I believe because of the `||` characters.  I tried using `^|^|` but this didn't work.

Any ideas?

```
(
echo update mytable set file_path = 'C' || substr(file_path, 2);
echo commit;
echo exit
) | sqlplus x/x@orcl
```

Comment: *this specific code doesn't work*: can you be a bit more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the SQL as file and redirect SQL Plus's input:

```
sqlplus x/x@orcl <sql.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CONCAT](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBUQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.oracle.com%2Fdocs%2Fcd%2FB19306_01%2Fserver.102%2Fb14200%2Ffunctions026.htm&rct=j&q=concat%20site%3Aoracle.com&ei=hopITYL4Ho3IvQONmNWxBQ&usg=AFQjCNG1bSXUNGsgmM9Lg0wrYE_hzmfesA&cad=rja) instead of the || operator

Comment: Using `concat` won't solve problem, because it is caused by the closing paranthesis, not by the `||`.

Answer (score 1):

Escaping the `||` with `^|^|` leaves you with yet another problem: cmd.exe thinks that the closing parenthesis of `substr(file_path, 2);` belongs to the opening parenthesis in the first line. It is therefore not printed to SQL*Plus, thus rendering the update statement to something like `update mytable set file_path = 'C' || substr(file_path, 2` which obviously cannot be interpreted by Oracle.

You can solve this if you put the entire update statement into double quotes and feed this to (yet another) cmd.exe, like so:

```
(
@echo select * from mytable;
@cmd /c "echo update mytable set file_path = 'C' ^|^| substr (file_path, 2);"
@echo commit;
@echo exit
) | sqlplus x/x@orcl
```